# Looking for list of USB OTG/USB Host officially supported in Android devices (allow connect USB sticks, etc) NON-rooted

Tags: usb-host-mode

I'm looking for a definitive list of Android devices that officially support USB On-the-go (OTG) / USB Host (non-rooted).

USB OTG/USB Host means that they can be used in a similar way to a PC whereby USB devices can be attached to them for them to access. E.g. memory sticks and other USB storage (mass storage class).

I am not looking for rooted devices (I know that such procedure can make a device support USB OTG/USB Host if the hardware supports it). I am looking for official support, out-of-the box.

Some devices may require adapter cables if necessary (i.e. micro USB to female USB socket).

So far I know at least one device that supports USB OTG / USB host out-of-the-box (non rooted):

The GoTab GBT740R 7" Android 4 Ice Cream Sandwich tablet, costing just 100 pounds or less in UK! This device has a full size USB female socket to support USB OTG / USB Host. A friend owns one, his USB memory sticks work in this - we can browse to the USB stick contents using Astro File Manager App on the tablet. (By the way, I don't work for GoTab). This seems to be a feature-rich device though for the price point: microSD and HDMI also supported.

Any more devices? usb.org doesn't seem to have a list, well I haven't found it yet, nor Wikipedia entries.

Comment: For a such device to support USB OTG, the mileage varies, depends on the kernel, but, expect a kernel v3.x.x upwards, combined with ICS/JB, then yes, there is a good guarantee that USB OTG would be available.

Comment: +1 Thanks @t0mm13b for your input. Assuming by Kernel you mean that in Linux then in what Android versions is this present? 2.3, 4? etc? Can the Kernel used vary with the Android version? I would guess hardware support needs to be present (i.e. not all USB hardware has OTG). Though I would prefer a definitive list of devices officially supporting USB OTG, perhaps with the extent as you infer, rather than making a guess myself given the OS version they are running.

Comment: Android version 4 upwards running kernel 3.x.x would be the best bet as google has incorporated new features relating to USB, including OTG mechanisms.

Comment: +1 t0mm13b this would help me compile a list myself in the event no-one else is forthcoming. Surprising that USB.org don't maintain such a list, surely people want to know what actual devices use this technology?

Comment: USB.org is a site governing the protocols, understanding the USB specifications and technical documents! It has nothing to do with listing devices that supports OTG :)

Comment: I think it's about time people realize that "definitive lists" can't exists in the Android world.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik well any list then. I've started one myself, as you can see. I don't think it's unreasonable for there to be a list of devices supporting certain functionality that the use might be looking for.

Comment: Any list should be doable even a very long one is. There're too many devices, variants firmwares etc. (plus all the Chinese ones! ) That's why I said it.

Comment: Chainfire (who make the [USB Host Diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics) app) have a list of the results of various devices and OS versions being tested for OTG support here http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/

Comment: @GAThrawn, how to search this list? Where to find ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's a start at a list (doesn't have to be definitive):

1. The GoTab GBT740R 7" Android 4 Ice Cream Sandwich tablet, costing
   just 100 pounds or less in UK! This device has a full size USB
   female socket to support USB OTG / USB Host. A friend owns one, his
   USB memory sticks work in this - we can browse to the USB stick
   contents using Astro File Manager App on the tablet.
2. @Philip Sheard's (yet unknown) "cheapo tablet just £70" - see his answer (Care to enlighten us at to the make and model, Philip? May be it is the same as the one I mention? Or not?)
3. **Update:** Acer Iconia Tab A200 (includes full-size USB A connector, takes flash keys no problem). Thanks @Michael Kohne for your answer.

I'll try to update as I find more... (feel free to contribute)

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer though I have upvoted other who contributed, I will update this list as I find more devices.

Answer (score 1):

Acer Iconia Tab A200 (includes full-size USB A connector, takes flash keys no problem)

Answer (score -2):

I bought a cheapo 7" tablet for just £70, and that has USB host. It is also 2.0, so it is very fast. As a developer I am very excited about the future of USB host, and I plan to support it in my own app.

Comment: and would you like to tell me what *make* and *model*  the tablet you have is? (Thanks - I will +1 your answer if you do).

Comment: And yes I'm "very excited" about the future of USB host too, seriously! I think, to date, it was the top thing missing from Android to make the platform a proper alternative to Windows or other Desktop OSs. Because with USB Host there is the potential to attach devices as you can with Windows, Mac or Linux. Devices such as mass storage, printers, backup devices (optical) and other specialist devices such as audio. This increases the functionality of the device and also makes it a viable *content creation* platform, not just for content consumption.

Comment: Indeed Adobe already have such content creation apps - photo and drawing for Android (and iPad.)